# Нужно ли создавать ODBC - подключения, если клиент и сервер - один и тот же ПК (расставить все точки над "и")

Tags: sql-server, odbc

Здравствуйте. Уже на протяжении нескольких дней пытаюсь разобраться с одним вопросом.
Я уже задавал этот вопрос, но внятного ответа так и не получил. Почему-то если неправильно сформулировал вопрос или же меньше знаешь в силу различных причин, тебя либо игнорят, либо считают почти - что умалишенным. Но все же.
Хочу получить ответ на вопрос, правильно ли у меня настроен MS SQL Server 2005 Express Edition. Мне необходимо чтобы БД администрировались и создавались запросы по ним на одном и том же ПК. Посмотрел видео урок начальной настройки сервера: [начальная конфигурация сервера](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD_L6Wb4jYs)

Если Вы действительно хотите помочь - посмотрите настройки после установки сервера в данном видео (последняя его минута). 
Читая в интернете различные статьи столкнулся с ODBC - подключениями. Да и в лабораторной они были. **Но в лабе сервер сетевой, а у меня локальный**. Нужно ли создавать мне ODBC - подключения для правильной работы, то есть, чтобы администрировать БД и создавать запросы из одного и того же ПК. Я читал, что ODBC нужны как для использования удаленными ПК так и локальным. Достаточно ли мне для вышепоставленной задачи тех настроек что есть в видео?

P.S.: может то, как я выразился в начале сообщения и покажется кому - то грубым, но поймите и меня я три дня пытаюсь сам разобратся в вопросе, а меня невзирая на фразы типа "лучше задать глупый вопрос, но узнать ответ" просто - напросто посылают куда подальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODBC - это одна из многочисленных технологий для доступа к базам данных.
Предоставляет программе унифицированное API, независимое от поставщика СУБД.

Уже давно является не модным.

К настройке собственно сервера никакого отношения не имеет.

Нужен только программам-клиентам, которые используют ODBC для доступа к серверу.

На клиенте, будь он удалённым или локальным, требуется установка драйвера ODBC для конкретной СУБД.
(Вместе с виндовсом поставляется некоторое количество ODBC драйверов)

Ещё раз. Требуется только в том случае, если ваша программа использует данную технологию.
Если используете для администрирования и/или запросов к MSSQL-серверу штатную консоль, то никакой ODBC ей никогда не был нужен.

Comment: о, спасибо. Вы даже не представляете себе, как мне помогли сейчас. Осмелюсь задать еще один вопрос. В свойствах протокола tcp/ip (менеджер конфируции) я указал порт 1433 в ipall. Зачем это делаеться и почему 1433? Единственное что, это, как я понял, какой - то специальный порт (видел спецификацию портов от microsoft).

Comment: Это стандартный порт СУБД MS SQL. Задаётся, чтобы был клиенты, которые не умеют находить динамическую конфигурацию сервера, подключались по стандартному известному порту. Можно написать любой, но 1433 закреплён за MS SQL.

Comment: еще раз спасибо) Если я попрошу Вас посмотреть еще одну тему, не сочтете наглостью?

Comment: @MuscledBoy Конечно сочту:) Валяй, в смысле показывай. Надеюсь это будет не видео.

Comment: Вот и он: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569915/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-sqlcmd-exe-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83