# Использование SQLCMD.exe для первой проверки доступа к серверу

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте. После установки MS SQL Server 2005 и Manager Studio, возникла необходимость проверки все ли работает правильно. Есть следующий код:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\pc77>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\b
inn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S 192.168.153.130\SQLEXPRESS,1433 -U sa -P 123 -W
1> select name, database_id, source_database_id, owner_sid from sys.databases
2> go name database_idsource_database_idowner_sid
```

Если я правильно понимаю этот код выводит названия баз данных из **sys.databases**, их id? Что делает 2 пункт? И ip-сервера - ip-ПК? 
Если все неправильно, скажите правильный ответ и как узнать ip-сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сервер локальный то ip 127.0.0.1 подойдёт (не подойдёт в очень запущенных экзотических случаях). Если удалённый, то узнайте его ip у администратора сервера.

Далее я MS SQL до такой степени никогда даже не пытался освоить, но могу предположить следующее:
1) по первому пункту вероятно понимаете правильно.
2) второй пункт - это продолжение первого. команда go запускает запрос, написанный выше, а name и т.д. - это вывод результата запроса

Comment: и тогда, остается только запустить командную строку и все это ввести?

Comment: кроме `name database_idsource_database_idowner_sid` естественно.

Comment: искренне благодарен Вам за проявленное терпение)